# google talk plugin arm architecture

Tags: plugins, google-chrome-extension, arm, raspberry-pi2

I am trying run a google hangouts based app on a raspberry pi 2 (Raspian OS). Unfortunately my research has led me to discover that Google have not created a plugin for ARM  architecture. Ive tried various methods including installing an Android OS but to no avail. Does anyone know a workaround or way of getting the Google talk plugin to install on no x86 or x64 systems?

Comment: Define "plugin" here that you refer to.

Comment: Apologies I mean Google Hangouts extension for Chromium browser. The term Google Talk plugin has been used interchangeably in any articles I have read.

Comment: I fail to see the problem; the current iteration of Google Hangouts _extension_ does not use NaCl/NPAPI modules at all, it's pure portable JS.